# Rspec | error superclass mismatch for class Cipher

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openssl

Since I've updated my ruby version from `2.4.1` to `2.4.4`, I face this error when I run **Rspec**.  I am really stuck now.

I am using rails `Rails 5.2.3` and Rbenv

I've tried the following with out any success...

```
gem uninstall openssl

gem install openssl
```

```
#I cut some line it was too big
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_ERROR_IN_CERT_NOT_BEFORE_FIELD
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_ERROR_IN_CERT_NOT_AFTER_FIELD
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_ERROR_IN_CRL_LAST_UPDATE_FIELD
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_ERROR_IN_CRL_NEXT_UPDATE_FIELD
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_OUT_OF_MEM
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_CERT_UNTRUSTED
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_CERT_REJECTED
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_SUBJECT_ISSUER_MISMATCH
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_AKID_SKID_MISMATCH
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_AKID_ISSUER_SERIAL_MISMATCH
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_KEYUSAGE_NO_CERTSIGN
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_ERR_APPLICATION_VERIFICATION
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK_ALL
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_IGNORE_CRITICAL
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_X509_STRICT
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::X509::V_FLAG_ALLOW_PROXY_CERTS
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOEXPLICIT
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCASIGN
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NODELEGATED
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOCHECKS
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::TRUSTOTHER
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPID_KEY
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::NOTIME
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_GOOD
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_REVOKED
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_CERTSTATUS_UNKNOWN
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_RESPID_NAME
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::OCSP::V_RESPID_KEY
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_RSA
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DSA
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DH
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_RAND
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_CIPHERS
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_DIGESTS
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_ALL
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Engine::METHOD_NONE
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::UNIVERSAL_TAG_NAME
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::EOC
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BOOLEAN
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::INTEGER
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-darwin18/openssl.bundle: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::ASN1::BIT_STRING
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.1.1/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of AES was here
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::CAST5
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.1.1/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of CAST5 was here
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::BF
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.1.1/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of BF was here
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::DES
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.1.1/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of DES was here
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::IDEA
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.1.1/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of IDEA was here
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC2
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.1.1/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC2 was here
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC4
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.1.1/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC4 was here
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:18: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::RC5
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.1.1/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:24: warning: previous definition of RC5 was here
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES128
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.1.1/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES128 was here
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES192
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.1.1/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES192 was here
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:28: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: already initialized constant OpenSSL::Cipher::AES256
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/openssl-2.1.1/lib/openssl/cipher.rb:33: warning: previous definition of AES256 was here
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated
/Users/johan/.rbenv/versions/2.4.4/lib/ruby/2.4.0/openssl/cipher.rb:64: warning: constant OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher is deprecated

An error occurred while loading ./spec/controllers/admin/orders_controller_spec.rb.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)

TypeError:
  superclass mismatch for class Cipher
# ./config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/controllers/admin/orders_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'

Randomized with seed 55176

Finished in 0.00052 seconds (files took 8.07 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples

Randomized with seed 55176

Coverage report generated for RSpec to /Users/johan/code/personnal_projects/kamelot/coverage. 288 / 1880 LOC (15.32%) covered.
```

Comment: Have you tried this https://github.com/bundler/bundler/pull/5388 ?

Comment: Installing a gem version of a core dependency can be a huge problem. You may want to remove the gem.

Comment: Oh... removing the gem  solved the problem ! thanks a lot !

Comment: Is it a gem that was in the old version of ruby ?